# vb.net ... use different file structure at run time when using openmode.random

Tags: vb.net, file, structure, record

How can I select which record structure to use based on certain criteria at run time?

My app looks for the version of a file and based on that information the app will then know which file structure to use.

The code as follows

```vb
If Mid(UltiVersion.versioncheck(anumber, server, database, uid, pwd), 9, 2) >= "20" Then
    Dim aud = New UltiVersion20.Audit
End If

If Mid(UltiVersion.versioncheck(anumber, server, database, uid, pwd), 9, 2) <= "20" Then
    Dim aud = New UltiVersion17.Audit
End If
```

I would like to select `Dim aud = New UltiVersion17.Audit` based on the version of the file at run time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to put the `Dim` to declare the type of the variable `aud` *outside* (as in, before) the `If` statements, then just set it inside the `If`. (P.S. Which one should it be for `= "20"`?)

Comment: If I do the following:                                                                                                                      Dim aud..... then inside the if statement "aud = New UltiVersion20.Auditver" or "aud = New UltiVersion17.Auditver" depending on the criteria I get a late binding error.

Comment: If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) then Visual Studio will be able to aid you in writing correct code.

Comment: Won't be able to use Option Strict On at this stage as there's a lot of code which will have to change:(    <=20 should be < 20

Comment: Not just `Dim aud` but `Dim aud As WhateverTypeItShouldBe`. If there's a lot of code to change now, just think how much worse it will be in the future when there's more code and something goes wrong at run-time because it used the wrong type automatically *somewhere*.